# How can I calculate and code a percentage?

Tags: r, math, formatting, percentage

It is easy to calculate a percentage, but how would someone go about printing the result as an actual percentage in R?

I tried to search the web and see if there were any functions that creates percentages for you, but I did not find anything. So, I am curious if there is another way to do this.

Comment: couldn't you use paste function to print a combination of actual results and %?

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like there is not a package that allows you to specifically print results in a percentage format, there is a workaround.

Here's an example of what your code should look like:

```
ex_percentage <- (sprintf("%.2f%%", (63/ 9323) * 100))
print(ex_percentage)

# or 

print(sprintf("%.2f%%", (63 / 9323) * 100))
```

So, what's happening here is that we are using the "sprintf" function to format the value of "ex_percentage" as a string with two decimal places and add the percentage symbol ("%") at the end.

Plug your equation after the *"%.2f%%",* and voila!

This can be useful formatting for markdown files.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like the following?

`x = c(1:6)`

[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

`paste(x,'%',sep = '')`

result:
[1] "1%"  "2%"  "3%"  "4%"  "5%"  "6%"  "7%"  "8%"  "9%"  "10%"

Comment: I like this method as it is one of the cleanest. However, I would add that the other method is useful because it formats and rounds digits. For example:

```` x <- c(1:6, 3.1415)
percentages <- sprintf("%.2f%%", x)
print(percentages)
````

vs

````
x <- c(1:6, 3.1415)
percentages <- paste(x, '%', sep = '')
print(percentages)
````


So, instead of just putting a percentage sign next to the number, the number is formatted with rounding and the labeling is consistent.

Comment: haha funny enough, I am definitely about to use your suggested code because I need those tertiary decimal points in my next equation... kudos!